# Spyder/Python: Figures are in the background

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am using Spyder to plot some figures in the interactive mode. The figures don't show up, they are in the background and I have to go to the taskbar to get focus to those windows. Below is the code

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x1,y1,z1, c='r', marker='o')
ax.scatter(x2,y2,z2, c='b', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this will be fixed in Matplotlib **2.1**, to be released shortly (don't know exactly when).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really something related to matplotlib. When I run a code in Spyder, the plot window always appears in the foreground, independent on the backend in use. Possibly the issue is more related to the operating system in use.